# Descriptive pipeline and docker as agent with tools

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I would like to use docker as the agent to run my Jenkins Job. I attempt to create a descriptive pipeline where I define the thing my job should do. As per definition I have the possibility to define tools that should be used in the agent. However, this does not appear to work with a docker container

Simplified JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'centos:7' }
    }
    tools {
        jdk 'openJDK 1.8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this job is as follows:

```
...
+ java -version
/home/jenkins/jenkins-test/workspace/Job@tmp/durable-442553e8/script.sh: line 1: java: command not found
...
```

The tool has been correctly defined in the Tools section of the Jenkins Configuration. It can be used in other Jobs that do use a physical machine as node.

Is there something I am missing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's because Java is part of Jenkins OS, not Docker. Dockers run in isolation to Jenkins host configuration and personally I found there are many pitfalls of Docker in Jenkins since everything needs to be mounted to the container from outside. All you want to run is a Java build, why not use a [Java Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=java&type=image)?

Comment: My build process compiles Java code and also C code so I chose to use docker as I am able to cross-build the code using different java versions and different glibc versions. That means I would create my own docker images with the combination of OS/Java that I need and then tell Jenkins to use those images as base. I am trying to use the Jenkins Agent at https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/agent as a template right now to create my own versions with the OSes i need.

Comment: Using your own version would be the easiest as you would otherwise require multiple nodes using multiple images to do this. If time is not a concern, then you can let Jenkins build the Docker Image [Jenkins Pipeline Agent](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) at runtime.